# How to bypass Jenkins Mirror

Tags: jenkins

I am installing Jenkins on Ubuntu cloud server and to run this whitelisted Jenkins URLs. pkg.jenkins.io

Now while installing the jenkins, got below error:

> Could not connect to jenkins.mirror.isppower.de:80 (178.33.33.67).

My queries here is, How to bypass or install from main site in place of mirror server. Or Is mirror IP will not change in future. how to whitelist all jenkins mirror ip. Or is there any way to by pass this.

Error:

> Get:37 http://repo-fr/wheezy/ wheezy/main lksctp-tools amd64
>   1.0.11+dfsg-2 [66.6 kB] Err http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ jenkins 2.32.2   Could not connect to
>   jenkins.mirror.isppower.de:80 (178.33.33.67). - connect (110:
>   Connection timed out) Fetched 46.9 MB in 1min 3s (737 kB/s) Failed to
>   fetch pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.32.2_all.deb 
>   Could not connect to jenkins.mirror.isppower.de:80 (178.33.33.67). -
>   connect (110: Connection timed out) E: Unable to fetch some archives,
>   maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of Jenkins mirrors and their current status:
http://mirrors.jenkins.io/status.html

As for the main site - there is no guarantee that it will keep its IP forever. You can whitelist all mirrors, so that if one fails - another will work, but IP addresses tend to change sooner or later.

That said, I believe what you refer to as the "main site" should actually be 
http://archives.jenkins-ci.org (also listed in the mirror list above)

Answer (score 0):

You should use http://archives.jenkins-ci.org, but I can see that this is down from last 2 days. In that case there should be some fallback?

[image: Jenkins Mirror Status]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your machine or cloud server has access to internet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).